# boost::filesystem::path and fopen()

Tags: c++, windows, fopen, std, boost-filesystem

I get error when I try to do this:

```
path p = "somepath";
FILE* file = fopen(p.c_str(), "r");
```

I get:

> argument of type "const boost::filesystem::path::value_type *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What system is this? Linux? Windows? It may fail because that `value_type` in Windows is `wchar_t`.

Comment: OK, then try `p.string().c_str()` instead of `p.c_str()`. The former implies a conversion to obtain the correct type.

Comment: p.string().c_str() works! Thanks.

Comment: OK, I added a response below. You can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're under Windows, that `value_type` is `wchar_t`, and will fail in the conversion for `fopen` (that needs a `char*`). As per the documentation, it seems you have to use the `string()` method to obtain a standard string with a default code conversor (`wchar_t` -> `char`):

```
FILE* file = fopen(p.string().c_str(), "r");
```

Comment: It should be noted that under certain circumstances the C++ standard library (e.g., `fopen()`) cannot be used to open a file on Windows, because the encoding Windows expects for the filename passed to `fopen` is incapable of representing that file's name. It's unclear when or if Windows will ever fix this bug. In the meantime Windows offers a non-standard function, _wfopen, as a workaround. So `_wfopen(p.c_str(),L"r")` should work.