# Conversion from c_str() to float

Tags: c++, boost

i've downloaded a code which implements a BoW (Bag of Words) and i get an error in this line:

```
float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str());
```

It says: argument of type "const boost::filesystem::path::value_type *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

I've been searching a little bit and I've seen that there's a problem with the conversion between this kind of string to a char but i couldn't find anything related to a float conversion.

I've also seen the diference between `string` and `c_str` and I suppose that the error is in the `atof` since I think that only can convert the `string` and not the `c_str`. Is this the possible error?

In addition I'm new in the boost library and I don't know hot to manage this situation.

Thank you very much and sorry for my english

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost::filesystem::path and fopen()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352641/boostfilesystempath-and-fopen)

Comment: oops, you're right, I did a fast search to see if someone had the same problem and I didn't see that one :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `boost::filesystem` why not use `boost::lexical_cast`?
If you work on Windows, then `atof` will not work with `path.c_str()`, since `value_type` is `wchar_t`.

```
float label = boost::lexical_cast<float>(entryPath.filename().string());
```

will work perfectly.

Or you simply can use

```
float label = atof(entryPath.filename().string().c_str());
```

Comment: On windows use _wtof for wchar_t strings

Comment: Thankyou very much @ForEveR! It seems that i'll have to keep an eye on the boost documentation.